# mdbootstrap form labels are overlapping the values

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

issue : form labels are overlapping the values
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FS71.png\](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FS71.png%5C)
the website : https://mail.syden.xyz
used : mdbootstrap and bootstrap4
did this :

```
<form class="row g-3 needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
    <i class="fas fa-user fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
    <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
      <input type="text" id="form3Example1c" class="form-control" mdbInput required />
      <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1c">Full Name</label>
      <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Please type your full name</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You could either hide labels for not empty inputs or create a class (the alternative to `active` , - e.g. `filled-input`, and add this class for all non-empty inputs).

Comment: i'm a newbie, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, migrating to Bootstrap 5 solved it (although the problem still occurs when I fill the text input programmatically, it only works well with manual input).